# Https call with client certificate from smartcard

Tags: c#, ssl, https, certificate, kerberos

How can I programmatically call https endpoint from c# that requires client certificate from smart-card?

Can I use store certificate or do I need to export required certificate to file?

I can access the endpoint without any problems from a browser, but when i do that from c# or node I get 401 unauthorized and I tried both options using store or importing certificate from file but that doesn't work for me.

Here's sample code:

```
const string url = "https://somesite.com/url";

var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
var certs = store.Certificates;

//var cert = new[] { X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("./m102044.cer") };     from cert exported from chrome

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ClientCertificates = certs;

var response = request.GetResponse();  // 401 unauthorized
```

Comment: Maybe this sample can help you: https://gist.github.com/michl86/5636381.

Comment: Thx, this line req.UseDefaultCredentials = true helped, do You know if there is similar option to this in node?